# How can I trigger a QGIS plugin Event from map refresh?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I have a combobox in my plugin (python Qt dockable widget) that needs to contain the currently open rasters.

How do I trigger an update of the plugin when something new gets added to the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of methods which I use (*note that it may not be the most efficient solution*):

- (using **Combo Box**) - Add the following line **before** you populate your combo box:

  ```
  self.dockwidget.comboBox.clear()
  ```

  Then when you add a new layer, close your plugin and open it again, the combo box should be re-populated with the new additions.

---

- (using **QgsMapLayerComboBox**) - This is **automatically** updated when any changes are made to the layer list (i.e. layers added/removed, names changed etc) without you having to refresh the plugin. I would recommend this method. You can set it so that it only recognises raster layers by using something like:

  ```
  self.dockwidget.mapLayerComboBox.setFilters( QgsMapLayerProxyModel.RasterLayer )
  ```

---

*Note: When using QGIS custom widgets, you may need to edit your dockwidget_base.ui file, find the `QgsMapLayerComboBox` class (usually at the end of the file) and replace the `<header>` to `qgis.gui.h`*.

Comment: This is great. I didn't even know there were custom QGIS controls. Are there others? I couldn't find a list of them anywhere.

Comment: @Raychaser - Awesome! Hmm only ones I know are those shown in the QT Designer, can't seem to find documentation for a list of them though.